# ps tool using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to run a batch script in remote server.So i am writing the code like this.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("psExec \\\\11.456.787.8 -u {} -p {} C:\\basicfolder\\".format('user','pwd')+'run_1523448627.15.bat',shell=True)
```

the error is

```
PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Couldn't access 11.456.787.8:
Access is denied.
5
```

but i am getting the error like Access denied.When i am manually trying the psexec command it is connecting and executing.but in python it is throwing error

Comment: `ipaddress` is not an IP address. It's the _string_ `ipaddress`...

Comment: i am giving the IP address of the server ,trying to access

Comment: no you're passing `psExec \\ipaddress ...` literally. And `Couldn't access ipaddress:` error message is the proof of that.

Comment: in place of ipaddress im giving like 11.456.787.8 and the error is also couldn't access 11.456.787.8:

Comment: can you paste a command line that works outside of python ?

Comment: `psExec \\11.456.787.8 -u user -p pwd C:\imaging\run.bat` am trying it manually in cmd it is connecting fine and running the batch file

Comment: sometimes it is working through the script and sometimes it is throwing Access denied error.What might be the issue,please help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting that something not shown in user name or password isn't properly escaped by the command line. You should rewrite your command using actual arguments:

```
import subprocess
username = "foo"
password = "whatever"
subprocess.call(["psExec","/accepteula",r"\\11.456.787.8","-u",username,"-p",password,"whateverfile.bat'])
```

so:

- split command into args
- remove `shell=True`
- add `/accepteula` no more popups for new profiles (bonus)

Comment: Still the same error I am trying the script in python command line before adding into the code